# How to Get the name of the Created Directory in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I am new to iOS , I have created this method to create a directory :

```
 static func fileHandler () {
    let Mainpath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let myPath = Mainpath + "/Images Folder "
    print (myPath)
    var Myobjbool :ObjCBool = true

    let isExist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: myPath, isDirectory: &Myobjbool)

    if isExist == false{
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: myPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            print (FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)
        }catch {
            print (error)
        }
    }

}
```

so my question is that , How can i return the path created by this function ?

Comment: You want to return the myPath??

Comment: yes i want to assign the newly created Directory to this Var